# How to download file from SQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, database, download

I saved content of a file in my sql database as longblob:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `upload` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`size` int(11) NOT NULL,
`content` longblob NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)     );
```

When i try to download it all I get is content written in code. I would like to create "save as" option when I click on a file.

This is how I store data:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO upload (name, size, type, content ) ".
"VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";
```

This is how I fetch data:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db('test', $con);
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT name, type, size, content " . "FROM upload WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
    list($name, $type, $size, $content) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    header("Content-length: $size");
    header("Content-type: $type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    echo $content;
    mysql_close();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Your code should work fine (although I'm not sure why you're doing the `flush` calls that might break output). What do you mean with 'code is being returned'?

Answer (score 0):

if you get a file that contains the code, you need to check your LAMP setup. As for your code, try removing the flush();

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't output any data (like the links) before outputting the image data. Anything else will corrupt the image.
2. Don't output headers after any content is already shown. Due to the nature of HTTP you cannot modify or add headers once output has started. That's why the content-type header is not showing and you see everything as HTML.